# Xamarin Custom BindableProperty with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a "desktop" page, to display icons (programs).

Now the basic idea is to use a 3x3 Grid and each Cell represents a spot for an icon.

I used to just call the View directly from my ViewModel, but I wanna stay true to MVVM and thought I'd attempt to get it to work using DataBinding and an ObservableCollection in a custom Grid class.

Here's my code

ViewModel.cs

```
/*
ViewModel for the DashboardView
*/
public class DashboardViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    INavigationService navigation;
    INetworkService network;

    public DashboardViewModel(INavigationService _navigation,
           INetworkService _network
           )
    {
        navigation = _navigation;
        network = _network;
        //modelService = _modelService;

        Startup();
    }

    /*
    Called when the application starts
    */
    public async void Startup()
    {
        //Bunch of network mumbojumbo that returns a bunch of services as JSON

        IList<JToken> results = result["data"]["services"].Children().ToList();
        foreach (JToken r in results)
        {
            ServiceModel temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceModel>(r.ToString());
            Services.Add(temp);
            Debug.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }

    /*
    Holds all services displayed on the dashboard
    */
    public IList<ServiceModel> Services { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ServiceModel>();
```

This is the relevant code in View.cs

```
        serviceBoard = new DashboardDesktop()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(0.94, 0.94, 0.94),

            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0.333, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0.333, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0.333, GridUnitType.Star) }
            },

            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(0.333, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(0.333, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(0.333, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
        };

        serviceBoard.SetBinding(DashboardDesktop.ServiceIconsProperty, "Services");
```

And here's the custom grid class where I attempt to create my ServiceIcon property that my ObservableCollection should bind to

```
public class DashboardDesktop : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ServiceIconsProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create
        (
        "ServiceIconsProperty",
        typeof(IList<ServiceModel>),
        typeof(DashboardDesktop),
        null,
        BindingMode.OneWay,
        (bindable, value) =>
        {
            return true;
        },
        (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            //do stuffs here
            //This is random stuff so I could add a breakpoint here
            int x = 10;
            var b = (IList<ServiceModel>)newValue;

            //Determine if an service have been removed or added
        });

    private IList<ServiceModel> Services { set; get; }


    public DashboardDesktop()
    {

    }
}
```

Now I've tried to put a breakpoint inside the "OnChanged" lambda function in the `ServiceIconProperty` but it never stops there even tho I add a lot of elements into the ObservableCollection in my ViewModel

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong.

1. You are creating a `Binding`, but not giving it a binding source
   (there are multiple ways to do that).
2. The propertyName parameter of `BindableProperty.Create()` should not include the "Property" suffix.
3. There is no reason to include a "Services" collection on your `DashboardDesktop` class.
4. You aren't providing any visuals for the `ServiceIcons` property.

To fix the first problem you simply need to set the `BindingSource` of `serviceBoard` to an instance of the viewmodel *OR* use a different overload of `SetBinding()` that allows you to specify the Source object.

Number four is pretty important too - but maybe you were planning to insert/remove visual children from within your property callback where the comment `//Determine if an service have been removed or added` is located?

In any case, I'm not sure that I would take this overall approach in the first place. It would be cleaner (and more in the spirit of XAML) to instead define your own custom templated layout container. Essentially, subclassing from `Layout<View>` and adding your grid-based positioning logic accordingly, and adding an `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate`. You should be able to look at the built-in `ListView` class to see how Xamarin implemented those features there and borrow from it.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the collection, not the collection's content.

So this binding is called only once (at the time it is created) and never again.

In the setter of Services, you have to subscribe to change events of the ObservableCollection object you received.

Comment: I dont get that, I want the event to fire when I call Services.Add not when I do Services = Somthing. I thought an ObservableCollection had this behaviour built in?

Comment: An event fires when you add an item to ObservableCollection. But your binding does not subscribe to it. As you have a specific presentation of your list items, you have to do that manually.

Comment: Could you show an example? I really dont get what you're trying to tell me, sorry. How do I subscribe to the Item add event from ObservableCollection?

Comment: I also would like to know how to subscribe to an ObservableCollection/List item add event.